# Magento Products display not displaying products in backend on reindex

Tags: magento

I am running Magento 1.8.1 with embeddedERP extension.
Not sure if extension is to blame for the behaviour, i don't think so as it seemed to work fine for a while after I installed the extension. The issue appears to relate to indexing.

I reindexed the site in response to a magento index aler. When I try to view products in the backend the page is blank but only from from the horizontal line below the Add New product button, there is no list of products but also no products table at all, rather than the products table with no rows one would expect.

I have tried deleting cache and session folders.
I've tried disabling cache.

I enabled logging and there isn't an exceptions.log file so presuming this means no exceptions happening.
I've logged in and out.

On one occasion when i tried creating a new product after saving it it displayed the products (new one and existing) but now that doesn't work either.
Previously, deleting session and cache and logging back in appeared to work but now doesn't.

Can anyone suggest how I can go about working out what is wrong. My magento debugging skills probably need some enhancing.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Came back to this and the site was then displaying an error:

Warning: Unknown: Unable to allocate memory for pool in [filepath]/Autoload.php 
This thread: 
http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards%20/viewthread/216180/#t462005
highlighted this is as an apc issue.

Altering the memory size to 256M as suggested solved this.

Hope this helps if anyone else gets this, still don't know why this issue showed a blank screen to start with, perhaps an APC caching issue?